# Undirected graph into Minimum cost union of paths

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, tree, minimum

I have to create a solution for a weighted undirected graph, passing through all the nodes, with a total minimum cost. Several paths, with no defined starting nodes, should end up and meet at one intersecting node. The number of the paths, and the number of the nodes included in a path are not pre-determined. The nodes can be passed more than once.

What kind of problem am I dealing with, possible algorithms as solution?
I suppose it should be a variation of a Minimum spanning tree (meaning using the intersection node as a starting point for the paths in stead of ending point)

Comment: Well, I didn't get you. It's not clear what is really given in this problem.

Comment: What is given is a graph of nodes. The reqirement is that all of the nodes need to be passed, such that the total cost of the passing is minimum. The passing is done starting paths from arbitrary nodes from the "periphery" of the graph, all reaching one certain (given) node in the center of the graph. The nodes can be visited more than once, so a path can go to visit a node, and then go back to the previously passed when continuing (if this satisfies the condition of minimum cost).

Comment: An alternative soliution would be to start the other way around - instead of getting from the starting nodes to reach the central node, to start from the central node and spread the routes out to the "periphery" nodes. Thus why I mentioned Spanning tree, but the branches should then be routes.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Minimum Cost Hamiltonian Circuit problem.

[Here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~meyer/math141/graphs2.html) you can read more about it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the structure is not a circuit. It should have a star-shape, meeting at one node which is predetermined, with an unknown number of hamiltonian paths

Answer (score 0):

It is a tree you are looking for and the problem is Minimum Spanning Tree-- MST: building a tree that spans all the nodes in graph and the cost of edges on the tree is minimum possible. It is a polynomial problem. Prim and Kruskal each have well-known algorithms for the solution.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm for Kruskal's algorithm.

Note: the problem is NP-complete when the tree is supposed to span a given proper subset of nodes instead of all nodes in the graph. This time it is known as the Steiner Minimal Tree problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but actually it should probably be a variation of MST, that gives a tree with several paths, each of them to be just one branch/path from the center node to a periphery node, passing nodes along the way, and not spanning in several branches.

Comment: Maybe you should formulate your problem more clearly. it still looks like MST or shortest path tree to me.

Comment: Well as I said, it is a variant of MST, with the difference that it's directed paths on an undirected graph (it starts from a "periphery" node and VISITS the nodes in a sequence along the way to reach a GIVEN node) with the possibility for a node/edge to be visited more times.

Comment: For example, to make it more clear, we can see it as a problem of getting several cars to pass all the cities in a region and all reach a "central" node, not minding how many cars, but just to make the total as cheap as possible. If we have a spanning, then several cars would start a trip, but they would meet in a point and repeat a portion of the routes when reaching the "central" node, which would increase the total cost. This is not taken into account in a classic MST problem formulation.